# connect-mongo: unserialize: options.unserialize || (x => x), SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Tags: node.js, connect-mongo

it's run well in the windows, but has the problem in ubuntu.
    root@tegra-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/pt/nodejs/new# node --harmony app.js

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/Trash/files/new/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:28
            unserialize: options.unserialize || (x => x),
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.local/share/Trash/files/new/node_modules/connect-mongo/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.local/share/Trash/files/new/app.js:11:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Comment: what version of node do you have on ubuntu?

Comment: The vesion of node is 0.10.37 on the board Jetson TK1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use arrow functions with node .10.*

Try ES5 instead

```
unserialize: options.unserialize || function(x) {return x;}
```